# How to differentiate Left to right and right to left alpha-beta pruning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I was trying to understand the concept between Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left alpha-beta pruning examples. Based on my understanding, according to the diagram below, is it true that Node K will be pruned for left-to-right alpha-beta pruning, since alpha>=beta? Moreover, for right-to-left alpha-beta pruning, is it correct that only node H, M, O will be pruned, as beta is smaller than alpha? Please highlight to me on this since I am new to alpha-beta pruning concept.

Thanks!

[Alpha Beta pruning Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7PEx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In **left-to-right** alpha-beta, K will be indeed pruned because : after J is computed (value 9), we know that E will value at least 9 (alpha = 9) which is already irrelevant for B (which must value less than 6 : beta = 6 after computing D). Therefore it's useless to compute K.

In **right-to-left**, when you start you have no value in your tree at all. The first value that will be computed is O (since you start from the right). You can't prune this node as you must compute it.
N is not pruned.
Thus G is equal to 10.
Thus C is less than 10 (beta = 10) : let's check his other child, F.

When you come to F, you know that beta = 10. You first check M, which does not trigger any pruning, then L. Now you know that C=1. Thus, A is greater or equal to 1 (alpha = 1 and beta = INFINITY).

You have to check for B, with a right-to-left scanning. By checking the nodes, there is no prune at all in this version of alpha-beta.

Comment: Hi, noted with thanks!